# Hightcharts getTimezoneOffset error moment_1.default.tz is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I want to use Highcharts `getTimezoneOffset` from this [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/time.getTimezoneOffset),

but error shown `moment_1.default.tz is not a function`.

This is the code:

```
  const config = {
  rangeSelector: {
     selected: 1
  },
  title: {
    text: 'aAAPL Stock Price'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }],
  time: {
    getTimezoneOffset: function (timestamp) {
      var zone = 'Europe/Oslo',
          timezoneOffset = -moment.tz(timestamp, zone).utcOffset();

      return timezoneOffset;
    }
  }
};

class App extends Component {   
    render() {
        const { dataResults } = this.state;
        const chartConfig = getConfig(dataResults);
        return <ReactHighstock config={chartConfig} />
    }
}

export default App;

render(<ReactHighstock config={config}/>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Full code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mybndy?embed=1&file=index.js)

Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: How about `import 'moment-timezone'`?

Comment: Thank you very much, i try to change `import moment` to `import moment-timezone` and it works.